# XSLT transform element value to childs value

Tags: xslt

My XML looks like this:

```
<element>
  <AttrValue someatt="a">
    <StyledElement>
      <Container />
      <StyledElement>
        <Paragraph />
        <StyledElement>
          <PlainText someValue="some Text" />
        </StyledElement>
      </StyledElement>
      <StyledElement>
        <Paragraph />
        <StyledElement>
          <PlainText TextValue="another Text" />
        </StyledElement>
      </StyledElement>
    </StyledElement>
  </AttrValue>
</element>
```

The output should look like this:

```
<element>
    <AttrValue someatt="a"> some Text , another Text (text from child nodes - seperated by comma) </AttrValue>
</element>
```

I have a multiple elements like this so maybe it should be with for-each?

Comment: and the output should look like this
and the output should look like this:

<element>
    <AttrValue someatt="a">
                 some Text , another Text( the text from the child nodes - seperated by a comma)
            </AttrValue>
</element>

i have a multiple elements like this so maybe it should be with for-each?
thanks alot...

Comment: Descriptive Titles, Code Language, Your end goal, some background, all make for a more descriptive question that is more likely to be answered.

Comment: Yeah, please clean up this question. The fact that you didn't even *ask* the question until a comment is confusing. Not sure you'll get any answers without fixing it.

Comment: Set the title of the question such that someone else will be able to reach this question when they are facing problem on similar lines.

Answer (score 1):

`<xsl:for-each>` is not necessary for this. I recommend separate templates as the more readable alternative:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
>

  <xsl:template match="element">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="AttrValue" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="AttrValue">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select=".//PlainText/@*" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="PlainText/@*">
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
    <xsl:if test="position() &lt; last()">, </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output with your source XML:

```
<element>
  <AttrValue someatt="a">some Text, another Text</AttrValue>
</element>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have assumed that the `TextValue` attribute of you second `<PlainText>` element is misstyped and actually is a `someValue` attribute.

Here is some XSLT that should do the job:

```
<xsl:template match="/element">
  <element>
    <xsl:for-each select="AttrValue">
      <AttrValue someatt="{@someatt}">
        <xsl:for-each select="//PlainText">
          <xsl:if test="position() != 0">, </xsl:if>
          <xsl:value-of select="@someValue"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </AttrValue>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </element>
</xsl:template>
```

This is basically a nested `<xsl:for-each>` loop. The only "trick" is how `position()` is used to place commas between text values.

Comment: ok, first of all thanks alot little change i had to do is to add '@' before the 'someValue'because its an attribute...
second if its only a part of big xml means element is wrap by other nodes and i want to keep the same structure can i use clone for the xml and change only the element part?